# Indication arrow or line showing two or more merged polygons

Tags: qgis, polygon

Is there a plugin or quick way of indicating that two or more polygons have been merged. I often produce maps that might reflect one compartment number and overall one area, but there may be two or three polygons that form that one compartment or overall area. Sometimes its not clear which polygons have been merged if you have many compartments.

I am using QGIS 3.6.3. I make forestry maps for plantation and sometimes a single compartment might have 3 polygons

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're talking about **multi-part polygons**. This is when a single polygon feature contains more than one part. To distinguish which features have multiple parts, use the `num_geometries()` function.

Use the Field Calculator to add a field called "num_parts", with the expression

```
  num_geometries($geometry)
```

[image]

Now you can use the "num_parts" field to distinguish which features have more than one part. EG, with a rule-based style:

[image]

You can also use the "num_parts" field in an expression in a label item in the print layout.

You can add a dashed outline surrounding all the parts of a multipart feature, by adding a "geometry generator" symbol layer to the `"num_parts" > 1` rule of the rule-based style shown above.

EG, here's what that looks like with the expression `complex_hull($geometry)`

[image]

and here's what it looks like with a 0.01 degree buffer: `convex_hull( buffer($geometry,0.01))`

[image]